# Delphi run as different user

Tags: delphi, winapi, cmd

I want a way in Delphi which I can run an exe file as a different user in order to gain different permissions. I do not want elevation of permissions.
Screenshot:

[image]

I want from delphi code to start an application as a different user as depicted in the picture.

Comment: Plz check your link. Its ambiguous.

Comment: @SpyrosKaravanis If a non admin runs an app that requires elevation then the over-the-shoulder UAC dialog is presented

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API function that you are looking for is [`CredUIPromptForCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177.aspx). This returns a username and password that you can pass to [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431.aspx).

Comment: @David I've tried this in c# with pInvoke, but didn't do the same as it does when running from shell with "Run as different user" from non-administrator using administrators credentials. It works of administrator is logged in in the background, or if some other proceed (whichever) is ran from shells run as different user command, but if not, my process called via CreateProcessWithLogonW doesn't have enough permissions when running from ReadOnly folder... Do you have any tips or ideas what else could/should be done? It seems that something is done different this way... :/